# Decoding a PRF file

Tags: c

Is there any way to decode a PICS Rules File?
Contains settings and preferences used by the Windows operating system.

The file is given by:

Q:F]9y3n5|dp:n4hU)qbs;!&-bzh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PICSRules spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-PICSRules) defines what PICS rules should look like. I don't think your file is one of those.

Is that the *entire* file contents above?

Are you sure that it's definitely a PICS rules file? There are many file types which use the .prf extension, perhaps it's one of those.

Comment: that was all i could get from the file after opening it in notepad. it is in encrypted form, and wanted to make some changes, if i could decrypt it. it is a system file and i think it got corrupted.